# Closed form for $\int\frac{e^{x/2}\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{3\cos x+4\sin x}}dx$

Tags: integration

What is the closed form for this integral
$$\int\frac{e^{x/2}\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{3\cos x+4\sin x}}dx$$

Comment: Please add any attempt you have made to solve the question or provide additional details to highlight where you need help.

Comment: 2 questions: a) what did you try (u-substitution, IBP...)? b) Where did what you did seem going in a wrong direction?

Comment: The answer is ${6 \over 25}e^{x/2} \Big( 4 \sin (x) + 3 \cos (x) \Big)^{2 \over 3} + C$. Wolfram can solve this.

Comment: @NikolaRistic Preped question